# How to fix a reason for a post deletion?

Tags: support

I have posted an answer and not only have gotten -1 votes for it, but also a delete (1). How can I view the delete (1) reason? I'd like to fix it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519604/given-an-infinite-poset-show-that-it-contains-either-a-infinite-chain-or-an-inf/519608#519608

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking that, in analogy to "closure reasons", there are also "deletion reasons". However, this is not the case - nothing in the Stack Exchange software asks for any reason to be given for a delete vote.

Of course, when someone casts a vote to delete, they have the option of explaining their reasons in a comment. You can ask for such an explanation via a comment of your own on the post. But **unless**, and **until**, the post is actually deleted, there really isn't anything you need to do, or **can** do; in particular, your meta post here is unnecessary. The software won't reveal who cast the delete votes until the deletion actually takes place (the threshold is 3 votes). If this becomes a pattern, i.e. you believe that someone is maliciously casting delete votes on your posts, then flag a moderator.